# Is there a free tool to measure idle wakeups on Windows?

Tags: windows, battery

I'm looking for something like [PowerTOP](https://01.org/powertop) on Linux or the energy tab of the [OSX Activity monitor](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5890) that will give me a count of idle wakeups on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For Intel CPUs:

> **Idle Wake-ups**
>
> Number of times a thread caused the system to wake up from idleness to
>   begin executing the thread.
>
> This metric is available in the Hardware Event Counts **viewpoint** if you
>   enabled the **Collect stacks** option during the hardware event-based
>   sampling analysis configuration.

[Read more here.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/496836)
I think the application name is **Intel VTune Amplifier** (PAID OR TRIAL VERSION).

**EDIT: FREE TOOLS**

1. [Perfmon](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-windows-performance-monitor-for-infrastructure-health)

Perfmon can be used to assist optimizations, monitoring results of tuning and configuration scenarios, and the understanding of a workload and its effect on resource usage to identify bottlenecks.

2. [PowerInformer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-powerinformer)

PowerInformer provides relevant and condensed platform power information to the developer, including for instance battery status, C and P state residency, interrupt rate and disk/file IO rates.

3. [Intel Application Energy Toolkit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/energy-efficient-software)

Application Energy Toolkit is a set of tools designed to help software developer and quality assurance teams to create and evaluate software applications for power awareness.

Source:Another [Superuser Question](https://superuser.com/questions/14332/powertop-for-windows).

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I'd be able to find a free tool (looks like VTune Amplifier is $899+). Updated the question.

Comment: OK, edited the answer. Hope one of the tools help, they provide features like Interrupt rate of the system etc. :)